# For loop value in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, for-loop

I'm able to get 5 value from for loop and I all values to be in the array.

Values are coming:

```
2020  
2024  
2028   
2032  
2036
```

It shold be like this:

```
var years= [2020, 2024, 2028, 2032, 2036];
```

```js
var td = new Date();
var cy = td.getFullYear();
ily_modulo = function(yr) {
  return !((yr % 4) || (!(yr % 100) && (yr % 400)))
}
var yLepa=[];
for (var yr = cy; yr <= cy+20; yr++) {
  if(ily_modulo(yr) == true){
    console.log(yr);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to store results inside an array? If so, just push the results inside the `yLepa` array, instead of loging it to the console with every iteration.

```js
var td = new Date();
var cy = td.getFullYear();
ily_modulo = function(yr) {
  return !((yr % 4) || (!(yr % 100) && (yr % 400)))
}
var yLepa = [];
for (var yr = cy; yr <= cy + 20; yr++) {
  if (ily_modulo(yr) == true) {
    yLepa.push(yr);
  }
}
console.log(yLepa);
```

Comment: Thank you. It was very basic and I was very close to this push method. But could figure it out.